# GLOB_RECURSE grabbing the wrong source file

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17, cmake-language, cmakelists-options

My source project directory is something like this,

```
|── CMakeLists.txt
|
├── src
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   └── a
|   |   |
|   |   |__ a.cpp
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   └── b
|       |
|       |__ b.cpp
|
|___test
      |
      |__test.cpp
```

I need to make a executable out of source a.cpp and b.cpp,

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*/ *.cpp)
```

I expect this to take a.cpp and b.cpp as the only source files, but when I print

```
message("All source file - ${SRC_FILES}")
```

It picks up test.cpp as well, which I don't know why it's happening. My understanding here is ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*/ *.cpp, in this statement
due to wildcard * it would go through each subdirectory of src folder, and then with *.cpp it would append all the cpp files inside each of these subdirectory.

Comment: Some studying on what wildcards do would probably be beneficial. If it's in the src directory at all and ends with cpp, it gets picked up. This is not weird behavior in the slightest.

Comment: Isn't my wildcard right ? I expect it to search in all the folder inside the src, I am not even givng the path of the test folder.

Comment: Why don't you explain what you think the wildcards are doing. It will at least highlight where your confusion lies.

Comment: Sure let me edit the question

Comment: @sweenish I have edited the question to tell my understanding

Comment: A **space** between `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*/` and `*.cpp` means that you have **two globbing expressions**. And file `test/test.cpp` matches the last one... The correct globbing expression, according to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob-recurse) and its example, is `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks a lot for pointing that :)

Comment: MIght as well bring up this from the documentation as well: 

We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree.